# What does "_wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument" error mean?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am rendering the Django form data to a template but every time when i visit to the url it shows me this error:

```
_wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Method in views.py:

```
 @login_required                              
 def subnet_network_detail(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = NetworkCreateForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             subnet = form.data['Subnet_Address']
             ip = form.data['IP_Address']
             user_hosts = get_hosts(user=request.user)
             hosts_list = host_subnet(user_hosts,subnet,ip)
             import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
     extra_context = {
         'hosts_list': hosts_list
         }
     return direct_to_template(request, 'networks/subnet_network.html',extra_context)
```

and urls.py:

```
  url(r'^network/netmask/select/$',
     'subnet_network_detail', name='subnet_network_detail')
```

I read from the other questions about this error but didn't get any idea. How to solve it?

Comment: Can you run the code through a debugger and see which line it is getting hung up on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`direct_to_template` is designed to be used in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^network/netmask/select/$', 'direct_to_template', {'template':'networks/subnet_network.html'}, name='subnet_network_detail')
```

You should be using [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) or [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) from within a view.

If you are using django 1.3 or later you can use:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
...
return render('networks/subnet_network.html', extra_context)
```

Or if you are using an earlier version:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
...
return render_to_response('networks/subnet_network.html', extra_context, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: If this error is occurring because of using ***direct_to_template*** .Would you please explain me more about that :)
As i have mentioned that i didn't found any right solution to the problem. I mean what is the link to rendering :)

Comment: Well, first can you see if using `render` or `render_to_response` fixes the problem?

Comment: First, i tried with the same code and it shows this error ***local variable 'hosts_list' referenced before assignment*** WOuld it be better if you explain me this. Then i removed the whole code to hide that error i mean the context part and it works fine! after using the render_to_response

Comment: I'm really not sure why you were getting that error with `direct_to_template`. It was coming from the wrapping code inside of the `login_required` decorator. But regardless, you shouldn't be using `direct_to_template` it's not the appropriate function to use and it's deprecated.

Comment: And would you please explain me about the "local variable 'hosts_list' referenced before assignment " error why is it occurring?

Comment: If `request.method` is not `POST` or `form.is_valid()` is `False` then you never define `hosts_list`. So when you try to set `hosts_list` in `extra_context` it is an error- you are referencing a variable that you never assigned.